# Some.asInstanceOf[T] or Some.get.asInstanceOf[T] for json

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have rdd with json rows:

```
val jsons = sc.textFile("hdfs://" + directory + "articles_json/*/*").flatMap(_.split("\n")).
                        map(x => JSON.parseFull(x))
```

Each json has field "dc:title" and i want to create rdd with these titles and with indexes.

```
val titles_rdd = jsons.filter(x => x.isDefined).
      map(x => x.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]].
      get("dc:title").get.asInstanceOf[String]).zipWithIndex()
```

But, i don't understand, should i use **.get** in `x => x.get.asInstanceOf` in map, or just `x => x.asInstanceOf`? And the same question about **.get** after `get("dc:title")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with sqlContext? Parsing is much simpler with this.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

It would be great, if you can give sample json of yours

**EDITED:**

i assume this is your question,

you have a list,

```
scala> val a = List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),None,Some(4))
a: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None, Some(4))
```

you want to know whether you should be using as below to retrieve values,

```
scala> val b = a.filter{_.isDefined}.map{x => x.get.asInstanceOf[Int]}
b: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**OR**

like this,

```
scala> val b = a.filter{_.isDefined}.map{x => x.asInstanceOf[Int]}
```

If you run above code, you'll get below exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer   at
>   scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)   at
>   $anonfun$2.apply(:8)   at $anonfun$2.apply(:8)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:272)   ... 33 elided

Reason is pretty simple, **you want value that is residing inside the Some**, but your question is about how to convert Some to your desired object.

in you above example , line 2,

```
map (x => x...)
```

x  will be of type Some ,if you want its value , you have to call get function or else you won't get the value.

below link will be of some help.
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Some

Please let me know if your question still stands unclarified

Comment: I have a lot of jsons.

Comment: Example: {
      "dc:title": "title", "creator": "creator" }

Comment: jsonFile - loads data from a directory of JSON files where each line of the files is a JSON object - this is from official doc, so if you have multiple json files in a dir ,it still works

Comment: Thanx for that, I'l try it. However, my main question about Option. Should I use .get.asInstanceOf or without .get?

Comment: For whoever the person who has marked both the answers down, please have the courtesy to give an explaination, we do deserve to know where we are going wrong (if it is wrong).

Answer (score -1):

If all the lines parse into JSON objects (ie. no arrays), you could use a for comprehension:

```
val titles_rdd = (for {
  json <- jsons
  jmap <- json
  jtitle <- jmap.get("dc:title")
} yield jtitle) zipWithIndex
```

Comment: Can the person who marked my answer down please comment to explain why?